PineconeConfigurationError: You haven't specified an Api-Key
## Vector Search DB In Pinecone
from pinecone import Pinecone, ServerlessSpec
import os

pc = Pinecone(api_key='a561dac3-3246-4aff-97fb-1f648d2ce750')
index_name = "text-embeddings"

if index_name not in pc.list_indexes().names():
    pc.create_index(
        name=index_name,
        dimension=384,
        metric="cosine",
        spec=ServerlessSpec(
            cloud='aws', 
            region='us-east-1'
        ) 
    ) 

from langchain_pinecone import PineconeVectorStore

namespace = "wondervector5000"

docsearch = PineconeVectorStore.from_documents(
    host="https://text-embeddings-nudmpai.svc.aped-4627-b74a.pinecone.io"
    documents=doc,
    index_name=index_name,
    embedding=embedding, 
    namespace=namespace 
)

Getting error as:
PineconeConfigurationError                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 5
      1 from langchain_pinecone import PineconeVectorStore
      3 namespace = "wondervector5000"
----> 5 docsearch = PineconeVectorStore.from_documents(
      6     documents=doc,
      7     index_name=index_name,
      8     embedding=embedding, 
      9     namespace=namespace 
     10 )

    File c:\Users\Prerna\Desktop\gameReccomender\myenv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\vectorstores.py:550, in VectorStore.from_documents(cls, documents, embedding, **kwargs)
        548 texts = [d.page_content for d in documents]
        549 metadatas = [d.metadata for d in documents]
    --> 550 return cls.from_texts(texts, embedding, metadatas=metadatas, **kwargs)
    
    File c:\Users\Prerna\Desktop\gameReccomender\myenv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_pinecone\vectorstores.py:438, in PineconeVectorStore.from_texts(cls, texts, embedding, metadatas, ids, batch_size, text_key, namespace, index_name, upsert_kwargs, pool_threads, embeddings_chunk_size, **kwargs)
        395 @classmethod
        396 def from_texts(
        397     cls,
       (...)
        409     **kwargs: Any,
        410 ) -> PineconeVectorStore:
        411     """Construct Pinecone wrapper from raw documents.
    ...
    ---> 54     raise PineconeConfigurationError("You haven't specified an Api-Key.")
         55 if not host:
         56     raise PineconeConfigurationError("You haven't specified a host.")
    
         PineconeConfigurationError: You haven't specified an Api-Key.

I am working for a RAG model but not able to add embeddings to the Pinecone vectorDB. The code includes both host and apikey still I am getting error as api-key and host not defined. I am using pinecone vectorDB.The error in detail has been provided in the above question.

Try this
import os
os.environ['PINECONE_API_KEY'] = "<YOUR-API-KEY>"

this sets the environment variable that the API is looking for.
Then you can have
pc = Pinecone()

